# Send and Receive data in uart with raspberry pi in c and wiringPi

Tags: raspbian, pi-2, uart, wiringpi

[image]

I do all things like below but it dont work well
this is my code  :

```c
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <errno.h>
    #include <wiringPi.h>
    #include <wiringSerial.h>
    int main ()
    {  

    int fd ;
    int count ;
    char ch[100];


     fd = serialOpen ("/dev/ttyAMA0", 9600);
     wiringPiSetup ();
    printf (" -------after wiringPiSetup----\n") ;
    serialPuts(fd,"hi dear"); //Sends the nul-terminated string to the serial device
    delay(2000);
    serialPrintf(fd,ch); //Emulates the system printf function to the serial device
    printf ("%s", ch) ;    
    printf (" -------end main----\n") ;
    return 0 ;
    }
```

The output is:

```
-------after wiringPiSetup----
-------end main----
```

Answer (score 1):

The program does what you have told it to do.

```
serialPuts(fd,"hi dear"); // write string to /dev/ttyAMA0

serialPrintf(fd,ch);      // write uninitialized string to /dev/ttyAMA0

printf ("%s", ch) ;       // write uninitialised string to stdout
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/49030/discussion-on-answer-by-joan-send-and-receive-data-in-uart-with-raspberry-pi-in).